# How do I Add Sum of DataGridView Rows of Same Date as New "Total" rows at the end of rows of same date?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView to display Data from DataTable "dtGrid". dtGrid has two Columns as "MyDate" and "Amount" ,Rows are like these,

```
dtGrid.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2020-09-14", 100 });
dtGrid.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2020-09-14", 150 });
dtGrid.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2020-09-14", 110 });
dtGrid.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2020-09-16", 200 });
dtGrid.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2020-09-16", 170 });
```

Now, I need to populate the DataGridView as

```
2020-09-14 |100
2020-09-14 |150
2020-09-14 |110
Total|360
2020-09-16 |200
2020-09-16 |170
Total|370
```

I have tried to check next row date of dtGrid in loop like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 < dtGrid.Rows.Count && dtGrid.Rows[i][0] != dtGrid.Rows[i + 1][0])
            {
                GridReport.Rows.Add(dtGrid.Rows[i][0], dtGrid.Rows[i][1]);
                var dtFiltered = dtGrid.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MyDate").ToString().Equals(dtGrid.Rows[i][0].ToString()))
                        .CopyToDataTable();
                var Total = dtFiltered.AsEnumerable()
                         .Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Amount"));

                GridReport.Rows.Add("Total:", Total);
            }
            else if(i + 1 < dtGrid.Rows.Count && dtGrid.Rows[i][0] == dtGrid.Rows[i + 1][0])
            {
                GridReport.Rows.Add(dtGrid.Rows[i][0], dtGrid.Rows[i][1]);
            }
            else if (i + 1 == dtGrid.Rows.Count)
            {
                GridReport.Rows.Add(dtGrid.Rows[i][0], dtGrid.Rows[i][1]);
                var dtFiltered = dtGrid.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MyDate").ToString().Equals(dtGrid.Rows[i][0].ToString()))
                        .CopyToDataTable();
                var Total = dtFiltered.AsEnumerable()
                         .Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Amount"));

                GridReport.Rows.Add("Total:", Total);
            }
        }
```

It just doesn't work. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, created a short version of the logic you created

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < dtGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   if (i == 0)
   {
      //Cells[1] will get amount
      total = Convert.ToInt32(dtGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
   } //Cells[0] will get date
   else if (dtGrid.Rows[i - 1].Cells[0].Value == dtGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value)
   {
      total = total + Convert.ToInt32(dtGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
   }
   else
   {
      dtGrid.Rows.Insert(i, "Total : ", total);
      //resets total value
      total = 0;
      //will add index position where total is inserted
      i = i + 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: After a little modification, It is working now! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution

```
dtGrid = new DataTable();
dtGrid.Columns.Add("MyDate", typeof(string));
dtGrid.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));

dtGrid.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2020-09-14", 100 });
dtGrid.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2020-09-14", 150 });
dtGrid.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2020-09-14", 110 });
dtGrid.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2020-09-16", 200 });
dtGrid.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2020-09-16", 170 });

var rows = dtGrid.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("MyDate"), row => row.Field<decimal>("Amount"))
    .Select(g => new { Date = g.Key, Amounts = string.Join(", ", g), Total = g.Sum() });

var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Amounts", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(decimal));

foreach (var row in rows)
    dt.Rows.Add(row.Date, row.Amounts, row.Total);

GridReport.DataSource = dt;
```

It will give the following result

```
Date       | Amounts       | Total
2020-09-14 | 100, 150, 110 | 360
2020-04-16 | 200, 170      | 370
```

Comment: The type of `MyDate` is wrong. The type of the resulting `Amounts` *debatable* (assume you have some hundreds values in that date). Can I suggest two DataTables that have a Relation on the DateTime Column? So, a master plus secondary View.

Comment: @Jimi - I copied the author's data. Although he writes that `MyDate` is the `DateTime` type, but in the code it is a `string`. But in any case, it does not matter and is easy to change.

Comment: `.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MyDate").ToString()`. Converts to string. But you have obligation to listen to what I say :)

Comment: @Jimi - I agree that this is a dubious decision. I would also look towards the Master/Detail view.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - Master/Detail model is in use but in this specific report the `Total` by `Date` need to be as a `row` below last entry of that `Date`.